# using slidorion plugin slider in sharepoint

Tags: jquery

Im using [this](http://slidorion.com/) jquery plugin slider in Sharepoint.When i hardcode the html inside a script editor or CEWP it works well. But when i load the html dynamically from a list. It doesnt work and render properly.

I have added all the references etc..Im 100 % i doing it well as there are no errors in firebug :(
Anyone used this particular plugin.If you have used something similar with the combination of image and accrodion please post it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've used it before in SP2010. Can't remember this Issue though. Can you share your code here?

Comment: Thanks Jan.
I did fix it by using window.load but still having issues with IE but works well in firefox.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please see the code sample with slidorion in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used (not optimal but working).

It uses the [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/), you should include that before this script. Note the "async: false;", this ensures the load script finishes before slidorion inits.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* gather content */
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "Featured",
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            var slideIndex = 1;
            $("#slider").append("<div id='slide" + slideIndex + "' class='slide'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Picture1") + "</div>");
            $("#accordion").append("<div class='link-header'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</div>");
            $("#accordion").append("<div class='link-content'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Body") + "</div>");
            slideIndex++;
            });
        }
    });
    /* Init slideshow */
    $('#slidorion').slidorion({
        speed: 1000,
        interval: 10000
    });
    //This should auto-adapt the image-height to the link-header height
    var accordionOuterHeight = $("#accordion").outerHeight();
    var linkHeaderHeights = 0;
    $(".link-header").each(function() {
        linkHeaderHeights += $(this).outerHeight();
    });
    var slideContentHeightMargin = $(".link-content").outerHeight() - $(".link-content").height();
    var slideHeight = accordionOuterHeight - linkHeaderHeights - slideContentHeightMargin;
    $(".link-content").css("height", slideHeight);
    //End auto-adapt
}); 
</script>

<div id="slidorion">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div id="accordion"></div>
</div>
```

There are several improvements possible. For example the slidorion init could be in the completefunc of the loadscript. Also the coding could be more compact.